# Make custom user table column filterable

Tags: customization, users

I am adding a new custom column to the users as below.  This adds the row and returns the correct value how I am unable to filter or order by it in the list.  Could someone explain how this is done?

```
    function new_modify_user_table( $column ) {
            $column['call_sign'] = 'Call Sign';
            return $column;
    }
    add_filter( 'manage_users_columns', 'new_modify_user_table' );

    function new_modify_user_table_row( $val, $column_name, $user_id ) {
    global $wpdb;
    get_currentuserinfo();

        $level = $wpdb->get_row('SELECT * FROM ' . $wpdb->prefix . 'ihc_user_levels WHERE user_id="' . $user_id . '";');
        $level_id = '';
        if($level) {
        $level_id = $level->level_id;

        $level_array = $wpdb->get_row('SELECT option_value FROM ' . $wpdb->prefix . 'options WHERE option_id="583";');
        $level_array = unserialize($level_array->option_value);
        $membership_level = $level_array[$level_id]['label'];
        } else {
        $membership_level = 'n/a';
        }


        $expire_date = date('d/m/Y', strtotime($level->expire_time) ) ;

        switch ($column_name) {
            case 'call_sign' :
                return (!empty(get_the_author_meta( 'call_sign', $user_id )) ? get_the_author_meta( 'call_sign', $user_id ): 'n/a');
                break;
        }
        return $val;
    }
    add_filter( 'manage_users_custom_column', 'new_modify_user_table_row', 10, 3 );`
```

Comment: Related: [How to make a custom column on the Users admin screen sortable?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/233900/191295)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This process is pretty straightforward. Add the following pieces of code to the current ( preferably child ) theme's `functions.php`.

**Step 1** - add new column to the users table list:

```
function wpse_add_user_table_list_column($column) {
    $column['call_sign'] = 'Call Sign';
    return $column;
}
add_filter('manage_users_columns', 'wpse_add_user_table_list_column');
```

**Step 2** - make this new column sortable:

```
function wpse_user_table_list_sortable_columns($columns) {
    $columns['call_sign'] = 'call_sign';
    return $columns;
}
add_filter('manage_users_sortable_columns', 'wpse_user_table_list_sortable_columns');
```

**Step 3** - provide value for this new column:

```
function wpse_user_table_list_column_value($val, $column_name, $user_id) {
    if('call_sign' === $column_name) {
        // code to set new value ( $new_value )
        return $new_value;
    }
    return $val;
}
add_filter('manage_users_custom_column', 'wpse_user_table_list_column_value', 10, 3);
```