# Custom column under All Users (multisite network admin)?

Tags: customization, multisite

I want to add a field/column for the super admin/multisite network page under All Users. I want to show a column called 'company' as a column under each user.
How do I make this possible? I am able to make this show up under each sites "All Users" but not on the Network Admin pages.

Thank you!

```
//Add column to Network Admin User panel list page
function add_user_columns( $defaults ) {
     $defaults['company'] = __('Company', 'user-column');
     return $defaults;
}
add_filter('wpmu_users_columns', 'add_user_columns', 15, 1);

//Print the user data in the new column
function add_custom_user_columns($value, $column_name, $id) {
      if( $column_name == 'company' ) {
        return get_the_author_meta( 'company', $id );
      }
}
add_action('wpmu_users_custom_column', 'add_custom_user_columns', 15, 3);
```

This function is taken directly from a function which works on the regular User list (not network). Replaced manage_users_columns with wpmu_users_columns and manage_users_custom_column with wpmu_users_custom_column. But it does not work in Network users list.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add custom column to Users admin panel](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/160422/add-custom-column-to-users-admin-panel)

Comment: But that one is not for Multisite Network. I am able to add the column to each single site. But how do I add it to the Multisite Network admin, All Users?

Comment: The [`manage_users_custom_column`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/manage_users_custom_column/) is used by the [`WP_MS_Users_List_Table`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_ms_users_list_table/) class, so you should be able to use it in the Multisite user list. If you want your column to *only* appear in the network user list, you can check to make sure you're on the Network User screen using [`get_current_screen()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_current_screen/).

Comment: After further investigation, it appears that the filter you want for the Network Admin user list is [`wpmu_users_columns`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wpmu_users_columns/) instead of `manage_users_custom_column`.

Comment: Great, that let's me create a column, but I cannot print any data in it. Updated the first post with the code I have now. I have taken code which works perfect on the regular users list and changed the filters. But it doesnt print anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is all you need to add a column to the network users table, put it before a chosen column, and add data to it.

```
add_filter( 'wpmu_users_columns', 'my_awesome_new_column' );

add_action( 'manage_users_custom_column', 'my_awesome_column_data', 10, 3 );

// Creates a new column in the network users table and puts it before a chosen column
function my_awesome_new_column( $columns ) {
    return my_awesome_add_element_to_array( $columns, 'my-awesome-column', 'Awesome', 'registered' );
}

// Adds data to our new column
function my_awesome_column_data( $value, $column_name, $user_id ) {

    // If this our column, we return our data
    if ( 'my-awesome-column' == $column_name ) {
        return 'Awesome user ID ' . intval( $user_id );
    }

    // If this is not any of our custom columns we just return the normal data
    return $value;
}

// Adds a new element in an array on the exact place we want (if possible).
function my_awesome_add_element_to_array( $original_array, $add_element_key, $add_element_value, $add_before_key ) {

    // This variable shows if we were able to add the element where we wanted
    $added = 0;

    // This will be the new array, it will include our element placed where we want
    $new_array = array();

    // We go through all the current elements and we add our new element on the place we want
    foreach( $original_array as $key => $value ) {

        // We put the element before the key we want
        if ( $key == $add_before_key ) {
            $new_array[ $add_element_key ] = $add_element_value;

            // We were able to add the element where we wanted so no need to add it again later
            $added = 1;
        }

        // All the normal elements remain and are added to the new array we made
        $new_array[ $key ] = $value;
    }

    // If we failed to add the element earlier (because the key we tried to add it in front of is gone) we add it now to the end
    if ( 0 == $added ) {
        $new_array[ $add_element_key ] = $add_element_value;
    }

    // We return the new array we made
    return $new_array;
}
```

Comment: Very nice work! That works great! I have one last question, is it possible to make the column sortable too?

Comment: @jockebq I am glad you like it. Unfortunately I haven't been able to make the sorting work. There is a way described that I assume is for non-multisite environment but I can't get it to work here. They use manage_users_sortable_columns to make the column clickable and also pre_user_query to set the sorting it self. It does not work for me though (possibly because of the multisite), here is a link, maybe you can make it work: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/27518/sortable-custom-columns-in-user-panel-users-php

Comment: Hi @Nikolay, do you guys know how to add a custom drop-down filter here

Comment: @RahulG Hi, I don't know about that.

Comment: thank you for your response.